Facing the error 500 while running appium script on real android device
I have written the appium script while running the script on the real android device. I am facing the 500 error
`import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.net.URL;
public class hyerTest1 {
static AndroidDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Set desired capabilities for the Android device and the app to be tested
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
    cap.setCapability("udid", "R5CRA1VFJAE"); // Device ID of the Android device
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "galaxy S21 5G"); // Name of the Android device
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "io.appium.android.apis"); // Package name of the app
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", "io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos"); // Activity name of the app
    cap.setCapability("noReset","True");

    // Specify the URL of the Appium server
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/");

    // Initialize the AndroidDriver with the specified capabilities and URL
    driver = new AndroidDriver(url, cap);

    // Print message to indicate that the application has started
    System.out.println("Application started!!!");
}

}
`
I have found the error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: zipAlignApk failed. Original error: Command ''C:\Users\Safiqur Rahman\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\35.0.0-rc3\zipalign.exe' -f 4 'C:\Users\Safiqur Rahman\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v1.18.0.apk' C:\Users\SAFIQU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2024328-9312-mpnq88.qs6m\appium.tmp' exited with code 1. Stdout: ''; Stderr: 'Unable to open 'C:\Users\Safiqur Rahman\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v1.18.0.apk' as zip archive: No error
'

appium is a buggy mess. There sometimes is no logical answer why you even get errors, because killing and restarting the software might fix it. it might not as well because there is something else. i dont believe anyone can remotely help with these appium errors.

Try with,

appium driver list -> make sure UIAUTOMATOR2 in the list, if not please install it in appium2.
If already there, may be try with uninstalling using -> appium driver uninstall UIAUTOMATOR2 -> then appium driver install UIAUTOMATOR2

